# Pipeline fails upon NuGetAuthenticate with unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an issue with a pipeline that used to work before upgrading my self-hosted Windows agent.

The pipeline is for a DotNet Core project, it first gets latest version from our Azure Repos.

At first, I add the error message ‘unable to get local issuer certificate’ when cloning the repo, I fixed it but copying the certificates from the previous version of the agent to the new version.

Then it needs to authenticate to NuGet before building the solution :

```
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
   nuGetServiceConnections: 'Our-NuGet-ServiceConnection'
   forceReinstallCredentialProvider: true
```

Here are the logs I get:

```
[section]Starting: Step 1: Authenticate with NuGet
[debug]Using node path: ***externals\node10\bin\node.exe
[debug]agent.TempDirectory=***_work\_temp
[debug]loading inputs and endpoints
[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_65dabc10-b00d-4b6e-850e-3a1ac2104576
[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_65dabc10-b00d-4b6e-850e-3a1ac2104576_APITOKEN
[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_PARAMETER_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION_ACCESSTOKEN
[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_65dabc10-b00d-4b6e-850e-3a1ac2104576
[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SCHEME_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
[debug]loading ENDPOINT_AUTH_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION
[debug]loading INPUT_FORCEREINSTALLCREDENTIALPROVIDER
[debug]loading INPUT_NUGETSERVICECONNECTIONS
[debug]loading SECRET_SCRIPTSREPOSITORY
[debug]loading SECRET_SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN
[debug]loaded 10
[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=http://proxy.***:443
[debug]Agent.ProxyUsername=undefined
[debug]Agent.ProxyPassword=undefined
[debug]Agent.ProxyBypassList=["***","localhost","127.0.0.1"]
[debug]expose agent proxy configuration.
[debug]Agent.CAInfo=undefined
[debug]Agent.ClientCert=undefined
[debug]Agent.SkipCertValidation=undefined
[debug]check path : ***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-artifacts-common\module.json
[debug]adding resource file: ***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-artifacts-common\module.json
[debug]system.culture=en-US
[debug]Resource file has already set to: ***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\node_modules\azure-pipelines-tasks-artifacts-common\module.json
[debug]check path : ***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\task.json
[debug]adding resource file: ***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\task.json
[debug]system.culture=en-US
[debug]forceReinstallCredentialProvider=true
Installing the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider (.NET Core) to 'C:\Users\***\.nuget\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft'. This credential provider is compatible with dotnet SDK 2.1.400 or later.
[debug]Removing 'C:\Users\***\.nuget\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft' before copying from '***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\CredentialProviderV2\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft' since overwrite is enabled
[debug]Copying from '***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\CredentialProviderV2\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft' to 'C:\Users\***\.nuget\plugins\netcore\CredentialProvider.Microsoft'

Installing the Azure Artifacts Credential Provider (.NET Framework) to 'C:\Users\***\.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft'. This credential provider is compatible with nuget.exe 4.8.0.5385 or later, and MSBuild 15.8.166.59604 or later.
[debug]Removing 'C:\Users\***\.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft' before copying from '***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\CredentialProviderV2\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft' since overwrite is enabled
[debug]Copying from '***_work\_tasks\NuGetAuthenticate_f5fd8599-ccfa-4d6e-b965-4d14bed7097b\0.181.0\CredentialProviderV2\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft' to 'C:\Users\***\.nuget\plugins\netfx\CredentialProvider.Microsoft'

[debug]nuGetServiceConnections=65dabc10-b00d-4b6e-850e-3a1ac2104576
[debug]65dabc10-b00d-4b6e-850e-3a1ac2104576=https://***.pkgs.visualstudio.com/33706eec-15bf-48db-846e-65c72f09c4c4/_packaging/**artifactfeed**/nuget/v3/index.json
[debug]65dabc10-b00d-4b6e-850e-3a1ac2104576 exists true
[debug]65dabc10-b00d-4b6e-850e-3a1ac2104576 auth scheme = Token
[debug]Found token service connection for package source https://***.pkgs.visualstudio.com/33706eec-15bf-48db-846e-65c72f09c4c4/_packaging/**artifactfeed**/nuget/v3/index.json
[debug]Finding the URI for the packaging service
[debug]Getting credentials for local feeds
[debug]SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
[debug]Got auth token
[debug]System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri=https://dev.azure.com/***/
[debug]System.ServerType=Hosted
[debug]Agent.ProxyUrl=http://proxy.***:443
[debug]Agent.ProxyUsername=undefined
[debug]Agent.ProxyPassword=undefined
[debug]Agent.ProxyBypassList=["***","localhost","127.0.0.1"]
[debug]Getting URI for area ID B3BE7473-68EA-4A81-BFC7-9530BAAA19AD from https://dev.azure.com/***/
[debug]Failed to obtain the service URI for area ID B3BE7473-68EA-4A81-BFC7-9530BAAA19AD
[debug]unable to get local issuer certificate
[debug]Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1088:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:666:8)
```

Could you please help ?

Thanks,
Claude

Comment: I'm sorry no, I've stopped working on this  :(